# How do i stop wp_insert_post from inserting same post three times?

Tags: wordpress

I used a cron job to fire a function that inserts a post each hour from an RSS feed URL but my problem is that it inserts the same post three times ago. I did all the necessary checking to see if the post exists before an insert but still the same problem, it inserts three posts at a go. The problem happens when am on a live web server, locally it works fine. But of all the methods(custom queries, same WordPress functions) I used to check if the post exists before an insert, the WordPress function `post_exists()` does not work at all. So can anyone help how do I solve this?

```
add_action('hourly', 'do_this_hourly'); // Cron Job

function do_this_hourly() {

    $feedUrl = www.example.com/rss;

    // Get RSS Feed(s)
    include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php' );

    add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'filter_to_cache' ); // Filter cache
    // Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.  
    $rss = fetch_feed($feedUrl);
    remove_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'filter_to_cache' ); // Filter cache

    $maxitems = 0;

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : // Checks that the object is created correctly

     // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 100. 
       $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 20 ); 

     // Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
     $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );

    endif;


    if ( $maxitems != 0 ) : 

        // Loop through each feed item and insert as post. 
        foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : 

                     $tit = wp_specialchars_decode(wp_strip_all_tags($item->get_title()), ENT_QUOTES);
                     $des = wp_specialchars_decode(wp_strip_all_tags($item->get_description()), ENT_QUOTES);
                     $lin = $item->get_permalink();
                     $cate = 3;
                     $title_chec = get_page_by_title( $tit, OBJECT, 'post' );

                     if ($title_chec == NULL) :

                            $the_article = array (
                                    'post_title'     => $tit,
                                    'post_content'   => $des,
                                    'post_status'    => 'publish',
                                    'post_author'    => 1,
                                    'post_category'  => array($cate),
                                    'meta_input'     => array (
                                             'source_url'   =>  $lin
                                     )
                            );

                            $new_post = wp_insert_post( $the_article ); //Post the post now.

                     endif; // Insert poat only if it doesn't exist 

        endforeach;
   endif; 

}
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code: shouldn't `$$tit` in `get_page_by_title( $$tit, OBJECT, 'post' );` be `$tit`?

Comment: Oh thanks just edited it but it's not actually problem! @cabrerahector

Comment: Also, you're double decoding the title: `$tit = wp_specialchars_decode(wp_strip_all_tags($item->get_title()), ENT_QUOTES);` and `'post_title'     => html_entity_decode($tit, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5),`. This might change the title in some situations (double decoding single quotes, for example) which would make your script fail to find a post with the same title. The first one is enough.

Comment: I would start by breaking this spagetti into smaller parts. Your function, if you must insist on not using testable OOP, should at least do just ONE thing at a time.

Comment: @JohnDee Could you please suggest how i could break this up and am not that ok with OOP.

Comment: I think there are many ways to check if a post exist or not in wordpress website. What I think is you can check by the permalink, you can check it with file_get_contents or curl , if a post exist it will return 200 header code, then your code sould stop working in that condition. And if it return 404 ( post not exist), your code will make a post. 

the second option is with wp rest api, get post by slug, you can check with http://yourdomain.com/wp-json/v2/posts?slug='.sanitize_title($yourtitle) ; and check if api response empty or not.. hope it helps

Comment: https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring